# Unable to connect to mssql server from php using mssql_connect

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have MySql database and i have master database in the MSSQL.So for accessing MSSQl i had installed PHP MSSQL driver and use the following code to connect to the MSSQL server from php

```
$server = "myip";
$dbname = "mydbname";
$dbuser = "myusername";
$dbpass = "mypassword";
$link = mssql_connect($server, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if (!$link) {
    die('Unable to connect!');
}
if (!mssql_select_db('mydbname', $link)) {
    die('Unable to select database!');
}
```

intially for 2-3 months it was working connectiovity.but suddenly we are not able to connect to the mssql server.

i tried to log whether this connection can give any error message.but it was not giving any error message.My server guy is telling from my php mysql server they are not at all getting any request and they are saying problem is at my end.Please help what can i do more.

**Update:-**

I had narrow down the issue. i have 6 server of mssql amongst all this six 3 are connected and 3 are not. the one which are connected are without service pack and ones which are not connecting are with service pack installed on the server.

So how can i connect to the server which has server pack installed.

Thanks

Comment: what is your PHP version ?

Comment: Are you running this code on server or on your localhost?

Comment: am running this on the server and this was working fine for 2-3 months and suddenly from last 10 days the connection was not able to done.

Comment: then use `localhost` probably with the port in  your $server param. Furthermore as per the [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php) `mssql` is not available on Windows "This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later."

Comment: my server is ubuntu server and i can see in the doc mssql_connect has been removed from 7.0.

Comment: ok i will check server name with localhost.

Comment: where can i check the log for connectivity ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) and see if this works or if it has some more information about possible network or authentication problems for you.

```
$dsn = 'mssql:dbname=' . $dbname . ';host=' . $server;

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

`mssql` package is deprecated and will not work in the future, so it is recommended to use other libraries anyway, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

Comment: is it mysql:dbname or mssql:dbname ?

Comment: It should be 'mssql' (I just corrected it), my browser auto-corrected it to 'mysql' ;-)

Comment: my php version is 5.5.9 and i can see mssql_connect is deprecated in 7. so this should work right

Comment: Yes, it should. I propose PDO only to try to get more information why your connect doesn't work, because it might give some more information than the old mssql driver. It is only a recommendation to use PDO in the future.

Comment: where can i check the log for connectivity ?

Comment: Normally errors should be go to the standard error, which depends on your php.ini settings. Set `ini_set("log_errors", 1);` to enable logging and `ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");` for output to a log file